# In a-frame 0.7.0, I can only use in Altspace VR. What's the sync to all users code in a-frame to attach to the cube code that changes color?

Tags: aframe

In a-frame 0.7.0, I can only use in *Altspace VR*.
What's the sync to all users code in a-frame to attach to the cube code that changes color?

I want everyone to see the same color of cube when clicked. I just need the sync to all users code please and thank you. It's for the lines of `change-color-on-click='green'` that I need sync to make this Q-Bert game.

I searched everywhere but I can't find a solution.
Can someone give me the sync to all users code?

This is my code:

```
<a-box color="blue" src="/vr/cube.jpg" rotation="0 225 0"  repeat="1 1" position="4.2 0 -8" scale="1 1 1" change-color-on-click='green'></a-box>
```